# FBS packed app open command prompt then closes

Tags: pyqt5, fbs

So, when I run `fbs run` the app runs perfectly. However, once I run `fbs freeze` and open the created .exe file the windows command prompt opens, does some stuff then closes (I am not able to retrieve the log). This happens with the app installed through the installer generated with `fbs installer` aswell. Running `fbs freeze --debug` will not show anything strange.

My app is supposed to open chrome through the chromewebdriver and a GUI window created with PyQt5.

I run python 3.6.7 and have the correct PyQt5 version (5.9.2).

**Edit**
It appeares that browser = webdriver.Chrome("src/main/resources/windows/chromedriver") is causing the problem. I store chromedriver.exe in src/main/resources/windows/

Here is my code:

```py
from fbs_runtime.application_context.PyQt5 import ApplicationContext
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QLayout,QGridLayout, QLabel, QTabWidget, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5 import QtCore

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome("src/main/resources/windows/chromedriver")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    allItems = {"type":[], "name":[], "size":[], "colour":[]}

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.main_widget = QTabWidget(self)
        self.main_widget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                QSizePolicy.Ignored)

        #Main Window

        self.itemWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.main_layout = QGridLayout(self.itemWidget)
        self.main_layout.sizeConstraint = QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint

        nameLabel = QLabel("Name")
        self.main_layout.addWidget(nameLabel, 0, 0)
        self.nameInput = QLineEdit()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.nameInput, 0, 1)

        self.main_widget.addTab(self.itemWidget, "Main")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    appctxt = ApplicationContext()
    window = MainWindow() #QMainWindow object
    window.resize(600, 300)
    window.show()
    exit_code = appctxt.app.exec_()    
    sys.exit(exit_code)
```

Let me know if you need more details.

Did some of you have any idea about what could cause this?

Comment: Okay first you are going to need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can figure out what IS going on and thus can perhaps help you  ---- that and your `__main__` should really be only 5 lines based on what you have here the last one being just `appctxt.exec()` as the other parts of that are no longer needed

Comment: I just edited the code and by doing this I found out that the problem came from "browser = webdriver.Chrome("src/main/resources/windows/chromedriver")". I guess I am not storing the web driver correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed my "bug". It turns out that `ApplicationContext.get_resource()` does not access the resource file situated at src\main\resources but accesses src\main\resources\base. Knowing this I was able to organize my project keeping this in mind. I hope this can help someone later.